# Is there a function in Arcmapper or Python/Pandas that can connect the endpoints of two polylines to each other for an entire dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, arcgis, arcmap

I am currently trying to create a group of polygons based off of two layer files I have that both contain shape files of glacier terminus lines in them. These lines are separated spatially based on the terminus position of the glaciers in each year. I want to calculate the are of ice loss for the glaciers, but I am trying to do this for every glacier in the dataset at once and not manually (200+ glaciers). Is there any way that I can automatically tell ARCGIS (or python/pandas) to create lines between the two terminus end points for all lines in both data sets?

I have already tried using the XY to line function in ArcMap, but because the terminus 2017 dataset is large then the one from 2000 I am getting errors when I try to make the polylines to connect the two terminus endpoints. I have additionally tried merging the two terminus track layers into one layer, but this did not help the situation.Finally, I edited the 2017 attribute table so the both the 2000 and 2017 attribute tables have the same number of entries, but when I use the XY to line function it generated a line length of 0.

I expect to have an output value for the line length in the hundreds or thousands (depending on difference between ice loss between glaciers), but every time I run the XY to line function I get a line length of 0 for all the output values.

Comment: Are your files polylines or polygons? Not clear from your frist paragraph. Suggest using polygons for everything, have one SHP for 2000 dataset and one SHP for 2017 dataset. Assuming you have the same glaciers in each, make sure they have the same name or unique_id field. Then can calculate area of each polygon and compare the two time frames.

Comment: also checkout https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example